# Is it Fuggle or Fuggles?

Tags: hops

This is maybe a silly question, but when you look around on the internet you see recipes mentioning Fuggle hops or Fuggles hops. I suppose there is only one "correct" spelling, so is it Fuggle or Fuggles?

Answer (score 2):

Searching around, you mostly find a reference to Fuggle. It's named after Richard Fuggle. I suppose that people who write Fuggles, really should write Fuggle's as in Fuggle's hops, like Cox's Orange Pippin.

Btw. Fuggles is also called Styrian Goldings ([Fuggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hop_varieties#Fuggle)).

Comment: +1 Learn something every day re. Styrian Goldings!  I'd gathered it wasn't really a close English Goldings relative, but didn't realise it was just Fuggles by a different name.